# How to use GC Monitor in Xcode 5 Instruments

Tags: objective-c, xcode, garbage-collection, xcode5, instruments

I am writing an app for Mac OS X with ARC activated.
I can't seem to use **Instruments** (Xcode 5) I am trying to run **GC Monitor** and I keep on hitting the wall with this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you the application target you're profiling does not support garbage collection. To use the Object Graph instrument, your application target must support garbage collection.

Apple is phasing out support for Objective-C garbage collection. You said you're using ARC. Keep using ARC, don't use garbage collection, and don't use the GC Monitor template in Instruments.